# Count and display downloads in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have a grid view with a hyperlink in it.
Is there a way to count clicks on this hyperlinks? Its to count how many times a document is downloaded.

This is what I have so far...

```
<Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />

            <asp:hyperlinkfield headertext="Download File " datatextfield="FileName" datanavigateurlfields="FileName" datanavigateurlformatstring="~/Files/{0}" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" 
                SortExpression="Username" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="College" HeaderText="College" 
                SortExpression="College" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Year" HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="Year" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Major" HeaderText="Major" SortExpression="Major" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Subject" HeaderText="Subject" 
                SortExpression="Subject" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Downloads" HeaderText="Downloads" 
                SortExpression="Downloads" />
        </Columns>
```

Comment: yes there is a way.. have you tried using a google search..there are so many examples as well as different ways you could do this.. check this link for starters.. the rest is up to you http://forums.asp.net/t/1222307.aspx/1

Comment: Hi DJ.
I already have the hyperlink working. Its counting the clicks that I am having a problem with.
Could not find anything specific that can help me in a gridview. Could only find button clicks to count, not hyperlinks.
Your link might work, thanks a million!

Comment: have you checked the link..if you can click a button and get the expected output you should be able to do the same with a link